# jQuery validate - multistep with only 1 button, ignore doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

If you have a form with multiple steps, but only 1 submit button, is it possible to run the validation only on the parts that are hidden, even as you navigate from step to step?

I know that by default it will ignore `:hidden` which is great.  But if I navigate to another 'section' of the form, then click submit again, it won't ignore the already validated fields that are now on the hidden section.

I want to only validate the section you're in, even if you have already validated a previous section.  In the fiddle below, if you submit when on step one, it'll validate it.  If you then go to step 2, it won't validate just step 2, it still thinks step 1 needs fixing.

Some context:  The plan ultimately is to flag that a section is not valid and apply a 'not valid' class to a particular step.  But, the user can work on any step at anytime as it's not necessarily linear.  Because of that, I need each section to validate completely seperately, **but I don't want 4 different forms** (don't have control over that).

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/effx3p45/14/)**

---

**HTML**

```
<ul id="Steps">
    <li><a href="#FormSignup_section1">Step 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#FormSignup_section2">Step 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#FormSignup_section3">Step 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#FormSignup_section4">Step 4</a></li>
</ul>
<form class="Form Form--signup" id="FormSignup">
    <fieldset id="FormSignup_section1" class="Form_section js-active">
        <h3>Step 1</h3>
        <div class="Form_field">
            <label>Text Input <abbr title="Required">*</abbr></label>
            <div class="Form_input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Text Input" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Form_field">
            <label>Text Input</label>
            <div class="Form_input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Text Input">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="FormSignup_section2" class="Form_section">
        <h3>Step 2</h3>
        <div class="Form_field">
            <label>Text Input <abbr title="Required">*</abbr></label>
            <div class="Form_input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Text Input" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Form_field">
            <label>Text Input</label>
            <div class="Form_input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Text Input">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="FormSignup_section3" class="Form_section">
        <h3>Step 3</h3>
        <div class="Form_field">
            <label>Text Input <abbr title="Required">*</abbr></label>
            <div class="Form_input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Text Input" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Form_field">
            <label>Text Input</label>
            <div class="Form_input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Text Input">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="FormSignup_section4" class="Form_section">
        <h3>Step 4</h3>
        <div class="Form_field">
            <label>Text Input <abbr title="Required">*</abbr></label>
            <div class="Form_input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Text Input" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Form_field">
            <label>Text Input</label>
            <div class="Form_input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Text Input">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="ControlBar">
        <button type="submit" id="FormSignup_submit" class="Btn Btn--alpha Btn--m">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS to hide the parts I don't want to validate:**

```
.Form_section {
    display: none;
    &.js-active {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

**JS: Controlling the steps and then validating the form**

```
var stepLink = $('#Steps a');
var form = $('#FormSignup');

stepLink.on('click', function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
    form.find(url).addClass('js-active').siblings('.Form_section').removeClass('js-active');
});

form.validate();
```

Comment: If you can't break the steps into individual `form` containers, then this whole thing will be much more complex and difficult to handle.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your jsFiddle.  It _appears_ to work but impossible to tell since you can't see what's happening on the hidden steps.  What's it doing that it's not supposed to do?  Do you want to ignore the hidden sections or not... your first two paragraphs are misleading in this regard.

Comment: _"is it possible to run the validation only on the parts that are hidden?"_  ~ Is this your root question?  You can set the `ignore` option to anything you wish, including disabling it entirely with `ignore: []`

Comment: @Sparky Thanks for the feedback.  The issue I'm having is that if you press submit when on step1 it'll validate step1.  If you then navigate to step2 and press submit, it won't validate step2 even though step1 is now hidden.  Make sense?

Comment: You've broken the plugin by not having a `name` attribute on each input.  http://jsfiddle.net/effx3p45/16/

Comment: Ah that's it!  Completely missed the name attribute (and not the first time I'm ashamed to admit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not see it at first, but one major problem is that you're missing a `name` attribute on the `input` elements.  Usually, when the `name` attribute is missing (or not unique) only the first element will be validated.

Every input **must** have a *unique* `name` attribute in order for this plugin to function properly.  It's how the plugin keeps track of the inputs.

**Updated:  http://jsfiddle.net/effx3p45/16/**